# Select max strike from contracts using lambda

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am trying to find the matching contracts of old and new and if found match select the highest strike price but instead of giving me a decimal I need to give me the Entry. how can I do this correctly?

```
Dim Contract as Entry = iContracts.Values.Where(Function(a) a.UnderlyingSymbol = iNew_Contract.UnderlyingSymbol).Max(Function(x) x.StrikePrice)

Value of type 'Decimal' cannot be converted to Entry
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter with Where, then order by StrikePrice:

```
Dim Contract as Entry = iContracts.Values
                        .Where(Function(a) a.UnderlyingSymbol = New_Contract.UnderlyingSymbol)
                        .OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.StrikePrice).FirstOrDefault
```